Automating the Mapping Between Apex Classes and Test Classes Using Dev Assistant by Agentforce
I'm working on a Salesforce project and need to create a mapping between Apex classes and their corresponding test classes. As an experiment, I'm using Dev Assistant by Agentforce through the VS Code plugin. So far, it has worked without issues for three classes, but in my organization, we have about 2600 test classes, so doing this manually is neither feasible nor smart.
Here's what I've done so far:

I created a bash script that identifies all the Apex test classes and returns a list of paths.

I have a prompt that, given the context of the class, generates the correct mapping (even if not perfect, developers can manually fine-tune it).

Now, I need to automate sending the questions and classes to Agentforce and saving all the responses in a file. The goal is to cover more than 99% of the classes with a single click.


To have an idea, this is current bash script:
#!/bin/bash
# Version 1.0.0

# Script to detect, with salesforce AI, mapping between apex-class and his test classes

# $1 path to 'apex folder'
APEX_FOLDER=${2:-"src/main/default/classes"}


CLASS_COUNT_APEX_TEST_CLASS=$(find "$APEX_FOLDER" -type f -name "*.cls" -exec grep -El "@isTest|static testMethod void" {} + | sort -u)

echo "Total test class: $(echo "$CLASS_COUNT_APEX_TEST_CLASS" | wc -l)"
echo ""

AI_PROMPT="chat, you should tell me which top-level Apex classes this test class tests. You should respond by writing: class name - test class name."

for APEX_TEST_CLASS in $CLASS_COUNT_APEX_TEST_CLASS; do
    echo "Processing $APEX_TEST_CLASS"
    echo "AI Response: $(sf-agent "$AI_PROMPT $(cat "$APEX_TEST_CLASS")")"
done

Note: i'm open to other ai solution, but i think AgentForce is the most fine tuned to analyze Apex Code
Has anyone experienced a similar process or can suggest a way to automate this procedure? Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!
Thanks in advance for your help!
